# Перестал работать pixel perfect in firefox

Tags: веб-программирование, firefox, firebug

Перестал работать pixel perfect in firefox. Windows 8
Поле чекбокса для активации оверлея не нажимается, не появляется галочка, не появляется картинка оверлея.
Я сносила аддон и ставила заново - нет результата.
Я удалила со всеми настройками файрфокс и поставила заново - нет результата.
Я удалила папку с настройками аддона  нет результата.
Я поставила более старую версию файрбаг - нет результата.

В чем причина? Как решить проблему?
Может у кого-то возникла такая же проблема?
При этом вчера выключался свет и апс почему-то не выдержал 10 секунд и комп выключился. Теперь у меня в портейбл версии фотошопа - все настройки стали по умолчанию, старые восстанвоить не получается. Может это как-то связано. Но если бы побились какие-то файлы, то переустановка помогла бы, а она не помогла.

Answer (score 1):

Это проблема самого FireFox. начиная с обновления 23 версии и выше Pixel Perfect не работает. (не работает сам Чекбокс)

Удалите полностью весь FireFox с всеми профилями и прочим и установите 22 версию FireFox.

P.S. После установки FireBug - если вдруг контекстное меню станет не таким, как обычно - идите в дополнения и обновите их. После этого все проблемы пропадут и всё будет работать. Удачи.)

Не забудьте запретить обновление FireFox. Если он снова обновится, то сами понимаете - проблема вернётся.

Comment: По количеству и скорости ответов я поняла, что попиксельной версткой никто (почти) не занимается :)))

Comment: Потому что это маразм.

Answer (score 0):

Смотрите верстку с компа или с сервера(удаленного или локального)?
Просто не знаю, как с pixel perfect для ff, а в pixel perfect для хрома, чтобы он включался для версток на компе, нужно особо проставить галочку
`Разрешить открывать файлы по ссылкам`

[image]

Comment: В хроме не знаю, в фф такого нет. Я для теста на компе мужа поставила файрфокс и эти 2 аддона - у него тоже не работает. Может проблема не у меня, а сейчас у всех она возникла в связи с каким-то обновлением? То ли браузера, то или еще чего...

Comment: Вот я сейчас попробовал установить пиксел перфект в фф (версия 23.0.1), у меня загрузить оверлей получилось, в списке оверлеев он отображается, но в окне браузера - нет, картинка не появляется.  
попробуйте chrome + picel perfect, имхо, хром намного удобнее для верстки.